# Images responsive with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have those images responsive when we see it with a phone. When I use it now, each of those images take all the width of the screen... I need it responsive.

[The images I am talking about :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp6AP.png)
AND Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Signature Helpers - En Marche</title>
    </head>
    <body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">
          <div>
            <a href="https://www.en-marche.fr/suivez-en-marche/?utm_source=SIGNATURE&utm_campaign=SIGNATURE&utm_medium=MAIL"> <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_suivez_nous.png" height="28"/></a><span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/EnMarche"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_facebook.png" height="28"/></a><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/enmarchefr/"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_insta.png" height="28"/></a><span><a href="https://twitter.com/enmarchefr"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_twitter.png" height="28"/></a><span>
            <br>
            <a href="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/Territoire/EN-MARCHE-KIT-DE-L-ENGAGE.pdf"> <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_kit.png" height="28"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.en-marche.fr/espaceperso/?utm_source=SIGNATURE&utm_campaign=SIGNATURE&utm_medium=MAIL"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_comite%CC%81s.png" height="28"/></a>
            <br>
            <a href="https://www.en-marche.fr/?utm_source=SIGNATURE&utm_campaign=SIGNATURE&utm_medium=MAIL"> <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/en-marche-fr/COMMUNICATION/SIGNATURE-E-MAIL/Signature_site.png" height="28"/></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You must put in the class attribute the responsive value, as follow:

```
<img class="img-responsive"  src="images/example.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

as answered by M. Doe you can use bootstrap's class `img-responsive`

```
<img class="img-responsive"  src="images/pic.png" alt="">
```

or you could use below css

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;  // to maintain aspect ratio
}
```

this will make sure your img max width no longer that screen width or browser width